# File path from within Azure CLI task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-cli, azure-cli2, azure-app-configuration

I have an Azure CLI task which references a PowerShell script (via build artifact) running `az` commands.  Most of these commands work successfully, but when attempting to execute the following command:

```
az appconfig kv import --name $resourceName -s file --path appconfig.json --format json
```

I've noticed that the information was not present against the Azure resource and the log file has "File is not available".

I must be referencing the file incorrectly from the build artifact but if anyone could provide some clarity around this that would be great.

Comment: Do you add `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/xxx` to the path? `System.ArtifactsDirectory`: The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. In addition , you can set `system.debug=true` to get more detailed log and share the error message here.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: apologies on the delayed response I had tried a few different values last one was System.DefaultWorkingDirectory

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT how/where do you add "system.debug=true"

Answer (score 0):

> I must be referencing the file incorrectly from the build artifact

You can try to add `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` to the json file path. For example: `--path $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/appconfig.json`.

`System.ArtifactsDirectory`: The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. Example: `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`

For details ,please refer to [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---system) .

Comment: It is causing the task to fail, System.ArtifactsDirectory is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function.....

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little tricky to figure out.

`System.ArtifactsDirectory` is the default variable that indicates the directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release.

However, to use a default variable in your script, you must first replace the `.` in the default variable names with `_`. For example, to print the value of artifact variable `System.ArtifactsDirectory` in a PowerShell script, you would have to use `$env:SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY`.

I have a similar setup and do it this way within my PowerShell script:

```sh
# Define the path to the file
$appSettingsFile="$env:SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY\<rest_of_the_path>\appconfig.json"

# Pass it to the Azure CLI command
az appconfig kv import -n $appConfigName -s file --path $appSettingsFile --format json --separator . --yes
```

It is also helpful to [view the current values of all variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#view-vars) to see what they contain before using them.

References:

- [Default variables - System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---system)
- [Using default variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#using-default-variables)